# AWS Cognito Custom Roles for Frontend RBAC

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have webapp with which I use Cognito for Authentication. I was hoping to use the same for Authorization/RBAC.

Ideally I would like to be able to create a group in Cognito like "Engineers" and anyone in the Engineer Group would have some custom roles such as "fileList:View, fileList:Edit, fileList:Delete",so that I can use this in a react frontend.

The thought is so Auth is completely controlled thru the ID Token generated by cognito.

Is this is possible thru cognito/amplify ?

Comment: yes, if you are using Amplify/AppSync you can add function resolvers to check the groups of the users and assign the correct permissions

Comment: @danielfranca can you please point me to some documentation ?

Comment: What is your backend? Is it AppSync?

Comment: If yes, you can use the @auth_aws directive https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/security.html

Comment: @danielfranca No I have a backend in RDS and NoSQL.